# How to configure vsdiffmerge tool as external diff/merge tool for VersionSql in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, git

Trying to configure vsdiffmerge tool as externaldiff/merge tool for VersionSql in Sql Server Management Studio, but can't get it to work. Anyone knows, what are the Args ?
[ArgsPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1iOp.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Visual Studio 2019 as your diff viewer, use these values for Path and Args.  Path may be different on your machine, as it varies by version and edition.

Path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe`

Args: `"%1" "%2" "Repository" "Database" /t`

For Merge, try this. I haven't tested it thoroughly and would appreciate your feedback.

Path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe`

Args: `/m "%1" "%2" "%2" "%out" "Repository" "Database" "Base" "Merged"`